# Posterior covariance from GPML toolbox

Tags: variance, covariance, posterior, gaussian-process

I am currently using the [GPML](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/code/matlab/doc/) toolbox to perform regression.

Generally, after learning the hyperparameters we can extract the posterior mean and variance by using the function in the toolbox as

```
[m s2] = gp(hyp2, @infExact, [], covfunc, likfunc, x, y, z);
```

Here, we can say that m is the Posterior mean and s2 is the posterior variance.
But the code only gives out the self-variance or variance at the target points and not the full covariance matrix.

$s2 = diagonal(k(x_{target},x_{target}'))$
A vector with only the diagonal terms.

How can I get the full covariance matrix between all the target points i.e. $k(x_{target},x_{target}')$?

I tried writing something like:

```
kTT = feval(covFunc{:}, hyp2.cov, xTarget);
kTI = feval(covFunc{:}, hyp2.cov, xTarget,x);
kII = feval(covFunc{:}, hyp2.cov, x);
sigma = exp(2*hypProd.lik)*eye(max(size(x))); 

% Posterior covariance matrix
kPost = kTT - kTI/(kII+sigma)*kTI';
```

But the diagonal variance values in the kPost matrix don't match those with the s2 matrix.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the problem, just writing the answer here so that it might be helpful to others.

After enough digging around I figured that:
**s2** is the variance of **$y_*$**
Whereas, **kPost** is the covariance of **$f_{*}$**

If we write the posterior of "f"
$f_{*} | x_{*}, y, x = GP(K_{*}(K+\sigma_{n}^{2}I)^{-1}y, K_{**}-K_{*}^{T}(K+\sigma_{n}^{2}I)^{-1}K_{*})$
This is equivalent to the kPost that I calculate in the question above.

But the GPML gives as an output 
$y_{*} | x_{*}, y, x = GP(K_{*}(K+\sigma_{n}^{2}I)^{-1}y, K_{**}-K_{*}^{T}(K+\sigma_{n}^{2}I)^{-1}K_{*}+\sigma_{n}^{2}I)$

The $y_*$ has an extra term in the covariance matrix which is the noise in the measurements.

Hence, 
$s2 = diagonal(kPost+\sigma_{n}^{2}I)$

Answer (score 2):

As you already answered yourself, the `m` and `s2` output variables are just the means and variances of prediction at the given points `z`.

However, I'd like to add that you can also get a posterior structure by calling the function as

```
[predmeans, predvars, latentmeans, latentvars, [], poststr] = gp(hyp, inffun, meanfun, covfun, likfun, xtrain, ytrain, xtest)
```

In this case, `poststr` is going to be a structure consisting of three fields: `alpha`, `sW` and `L` which are supposed to be used to construct the posterior means and variances using the formula given in [the GPML toolbox for Matlab manual](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/code/matlab/doc/manual.pdf), page 4.

Also of note: this posterior structure can also be returned when training (instead of predicting, as in your example as well as the one I wrote out above), using a function call like

```
[negloglik, derivnegloglik, poststr] = gp(hyp, inffun, meanfun, covfun, likfun, xtrain, ytrain)
```